# Unable to access DesiredCapabilities methods

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

My question is :
I created `DesiredCapabilities` instance  shown in below code :

```
public class TestCommons  {

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    public void setUp() {

        driver.navigate().to(
                "http://toolsqa.wpengine.com/automation-practice-form/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public void tearDown() {

        driver.close();
    }

}
```

When I write  capabilities. in the next line am not getting any eclipse intellisense options. And if I write `capabilities.setCapability` , its showing error.
As in the code , in `setUp()` method  when i write capabilities. I get options. 
Why am I not getting eclipse intellisense outside the method?
Attached screenshot.[DesiredCapabilities instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZRMu.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have to write `capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);` **inside a method**, not only inside a class.
This applies to all method calls with the void return type.

A good place for it is one of `@Before`-annotated methods (like `@BeforeClass`) or, in some cases, it may be the class constructor.

Comment: Thanks . Yeah its working when i write inside method, I would like to know why isnt this working when writing inside class and outside method

Comment: @nznn It doesn't work outside of the method because that isn't valid Java and Eclipse doesn't understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You will get DesiredCapabilities properties are inside the Methods only not out method or inside the class.